# Changing power button behavior to reset/restart in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, shutdown

I have searched all over and cannot find a definitive answer about whether or not it is possible to set a chassis power button to reset/restart instead of shutdown.

I know that the options available under "Power Options" are only "Do Nothing", "Sleep" and "Shutdown".

Is it possible for me to set a power button on a Intel NUC i3 to restart the PC and not shut it down?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this in Windows 7, only in some Windows Server versions.

The closest you could get to this would be getting a 3rd-party keyboard shortcut software and mapping a hotkey combination to execute a reboot batch.